# how to classify values into factors in r

Tags: r, regression, r-factor

I used logistic regression to get some probabilities of y, I did the following:

```
fit.model <- glm (y~ x1 +x2 , data = mydata, family=binomial)  
pred_model<- plogis(predict(fit.model, mydata))
```

Now, I want to classify the probabilities using a cut off value of 0.5 to yes or no
I tried this, but doesn't work probably

```
class <- ifelse(pred_model>0.5, "yes" , "no" )
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what `plogis` does. Read `?predict.glm` and try using `type = "response"` instead. More generally, "it doesn't work" is not a sufficiently specific description of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
class <- factor(ifelse(pred_model>0.5, "yes", "no"), c("yes", "no"))
```

Comment: Thank you Vincent I tried your codes and it gives the correct answer, and thanks Joran for your comment

Comment: You're welcome. :)
You should put your question as answered now so other unanswered ones are more likely to be seen. ;)